# Has anyone tried to lookup external API's using PySpark?

Tags: pyspark, python-requests

Checking to see if anyone has used pyspark of distributing data and use the same to lookup an external API and store results.

I am working on this problem:
I have a source file with say 100000 rows of User Agents. I have to lookup an external API (using requests) and get characteristics of the User Agents and store the same. I was able to accomplish this with Queues and Threads in a reasonable manner.
However, I noticed that 100k row count might turn up to a million.

I was thinking if I could use Spark to distribute this data and perform this API lookup operation in parallel fashion using executors.

Has anyone accomplished this ?

Comment: Can u explain about external api. Is it connecting to some database or file system. Spark support jdbc connection. If that helps.

Comment: It's a REST based API that you provide a User Agent and get a JSON response back.